# Using both cookies and tokens different web api endpoints in the same app

Tags: cookies, asp.net-web-api2, token, identityserver3

Is it possible to have both token based authentication and cookie based authentication for different web api end points in the same app? Can we use app.map to do such a thing?

Comment: Are you making cross-origin requests, or are they to the same domain the app is served at?

Comment: there are both. token based authentication is needed for cross origin requests and cookie based authentication is needed for the same domain requests.